# How to hide part of a URL from clients using htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm working on a website running on an Apache server. The PHP factory makes and takes URLs that look like this:

```
site.com/page/view/[id]/[vanity-url]
```

However, the client wants to hide part of the URL from view, so in the browser it appears as:

```
site.com/[vanity-url]
```

The server still needs to see the full URL.

I've tried various RewriteRules after hours of searching, and the closest I seem to have come is:

```
RewriteRule ^page/view/(.*)/(.*)$ /$2 [R,L]
```

...but that doesn't seem to be doing anything. I know for sure that my .htacces is working.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this isn't possible. Let me explain why:

You state that the server needs to see the full URL. Specifically, this includes the `id` segment, which I am sure your framework needs (it wouln't need it if the server only needs to see the vanity segment). The code you have provided *redirects* the full URL to the vanity URL, thus making the full URL invisible to the server for the next request.

So, navigating to `/page/view/2/about-us` would *redirect* to `/about-us`, and the address bar would change to reflect that. This causes a *new* request to be sent to the server, containing only the `/about-us` vanity URL.

As a result, you would need to *rewrite* the vanity URL back to the full URL (without redirecting, so that the `/about-us` stays in the address bar as-is), but you wouldn't be able to do this, as the vanity URL does not contain the `id` segment, which seems to be a requirement for the framework to serve the correct response. Keep in mind that Apache cannot guess the ID for that particular vanity URL.